# Converting xsxl into csv

Tags: excel, csv, type-conversion

I'm wondering if there is a way to convert an .xsxl file into .csv while preserving everything in its entirety.

I have a column that for some rows has values like 0738794E5 and when I convert it through "save as", the value turns to 7.39E+10. I understand that some values which have an "E" will be turned to the latter format but this conversion is no use to me since that "E" doesn't stand for exponentiation.

Is there a setting to preserve the values the way they are i.e. text/string?

Comment: You may want to select the columns in question and make sure their type is set to "text", rather than "general".

Comment: Good suggestion. Still no luck though

Comment: Hmm...this is kind of a bizzarre workaround, but it might give you what you want if you have access to some unix commands.  Try saving the file as a tab-delimited text file, then use something like `cat file.txt | tr "\t" "," > file.csv` to change all the tabs to commas.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to create an additional (or replacement) column that has the target values either enclosed in double quotes or prepended by an alpha character.

The quotes or alpha character will guarantee that the problem values come in as text. When the csv file is opened, the quotes or alpha will still be there, so you would need to use a string operation (MID or RIGHT, probably) to recover the original string values.

Answer (score 0):

My dilemma wasn't real and only appeared to be so.

When I convert the .xlsx into .csv and open the .csv, it shows the improperly-converted values.

However, when I run my application, read from the csv, and output what's been read, I get the values contained within the .xlsx just like I wanted.

I'm not sure how/why this is the way it is but it works now.